# If the probability of an event happening in 1 second is 10%, what is the probability that it happens in 0.1s?

Tags: probability

How do I convert probabilities between time scales?

My current understanding is that I can use the following:

$p_{\text{new}} = 1 - (1 - p_{\text{orig}})^{\text{int}_{\text{new}} / \text{int}_{\text{orig}}}$

so I would get:

$p_{\text{new}} = 1 - (1 - 0.1)^{0.1/1}$

Is this accurate, and if so, what is the name of this formula/theory?

I've also looked at the Poisson distribution, which looks like it may also apply, but I'm not sure how that differs from the above method.

EDIT: I should probably mention that I'm talking about stochastic mechanisms here that are completely independent.

Comment: This isn't really well-defined without some extra assumptions. For example, if you own a clock, the probability that the second hand moves in 1 second is 100%. But the probability that it moves in 0.1s isn't 0 (as your formula predicts). Also, the probability that the second hand moves in a 0.1s interval depends on what assumptions you make about the start time of the interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under appropriate assumptions, this is correct.

Specifically, for this calculation to work out, we must assume that the following events are independent and equally likely (where we have a stopwatch reading out in seconds):

- An event occurs when the stopwatch reads between $0$ and $0.1$.
- An event occurs when the stopwatch reads between $0.1$ and $0.2$.

...

- An event occurs when the stopwatch reads between $0.9$ and $1.0$.

If we let $p_{\text{new}}$ be the probability of any individual event occurring, then, since we assumed they are independent, the probability of *none* of them occurring is
$$(1-p_{\text{new}})^{10}$$
so the probability of at least one of them occurring is
$$p_{\text{original}}=1-(1-p_{\text{new}})^{10}.$$
Solving for $p_{\text{new}}$ would give your formula
$$p_{\text{new}}=1-(1-p_{\text{original}})^{1/10}.$$

Note that you usually need to be careful about the assumption of independence - some events are appropriate to measure that way (e.g. "a raindrop hit a piece of paper") and some are definitely not (e.g. "a single randomly chosen time in the next 10 seconds was in this period" or, as suggested in a comment, "the probability that the seconds hand of a clock moves in the next 0.1 seconds").

---

As you suggest, this formula can be generalized to say that, under similar assumptions, to say that
$$p_{\text{new}}=1-(1-p_{\text{original}})^{d_{\text{new}}/d_{\text{original}}}.$$
where $d_{\text{new}}$ is the new duration and $d_{\text{original}}$ is the original one. Proving this is basically just repeating the above argument when the quotient in the exponent is rational and then doing a little analysis to handle the other cases.

---

The connection to the Poisson distribution is that the Poisson distribution considers a similar setup. It measures how many times some event occurs, assuming that the events "it occurs at least once between time $x$ and $y$" are independent of each other (so long as the time intervals do not overlap) and that their probability only depends on the duration between $x$ and $y$.

The Poisson distribution is, given the expected number of occurrences in some duration and these assumptions of independence, the distribution of the *count* of events in a duration. So, for instance, if you expected $1.5$ events to happen each second (on average), it would tell you things like "the probability of $5$ events happening in that second is $\frac{(1.5)^5e^{-1.5}}{5!}$."

You could solve the question using these distributions by noting that, under these assumptions, if we expected $x$ events to happen per second, then the probability of *no* events happening is $e^{-x}$, per the Poisson distribution's definition. We'd expect $\frac{1}{10}x$ events to happen per $0.1$ seconds under the given assumptions - which would yield the probability of *none* of them happening to be $e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}$ - which aligns with your calculations.

Comment: Thank you that was a very thorough reply. Am I correct in thinking that the simple formula you wrote above (p_new) would be best suited for converting probabilities across different time scales, while the Poisson distribution's probability mass function would be used when calculating an unknown probability?

Comment: @james_erikson The formula I wrote converts between probabilities of events happening over different durations (under appropriate assumptions). The Poisson distribution still needs to know the probability (or the expected number of occurrences - which is easy to derive from the probability and vice versa) - but it's a richer structure that answers not just "did it happen at all?" but also "how many times did it happen?"

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

Here's a hint that might help clarify your thinking: Suppose the probability that the event happens in some interval of .1 seconds is $p$. Then the probability that it **doesn't** happen in some interval of .1 seconds is $1-p$. The probability that it doesn't happen in **ten consecutive intervals** of .1 seconds is $(1-p)^{10}$, and this has to equal what?